# save and fetch multiple drop down values as comma seperated string in a single database column

Tags: php, mysql

i have a drop down box, in which opiton values and id are fetched from database table:

```
First table:
----------
id | value
----------
1  | Value1
2  | Value2
3  | Value3
-----------

<option id=1>Value1</option>
<option id=2>Value2</optoin>
<option id=3>Value3</option>
```

Now i want to save the ids of  selected values like this

Second Table: (let us assume i selected first two options)

```
id | Selected
-------------
1  |   1,2
------------
```

Now, i want to fetch the the string and show the corresponding selected options

any suggestions???

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = 'SELECT value FROM firsttable WHERE id IN (' . $fieldvalue . ')';
```

Just retreive the value from the database and put it in the query, it's already formatted as IN wants.  Then do a loop through the results and all.

Comment: i think you are not getting my question.....i asked how to save the fields  comma seperated in single column and the how to retrive them and show the corresponding selected options

Comment: @sumitmann: Note that - this community is to help out people, not to write a whole script or work for you.

Comment: i am not asking for full script, i am just asking a simple solution in  english, i can make script by myself

Comment: Grab csv from table, plug in query I posted, do query, loop through results, printing values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't insert them in single column as comma separated instead add a row for each selection.

```
id | Selected
-------------
1  |   1
2  |   2
------------
```

Comment: i have to save them as comma seperated corresponding to the unique id into the second table

Comment: @sumitmann: So, you want to run on the way which will be more problematic for you. I doubt, Do you really want?

Comment: I love how everyone says NORMALIZE instead of answering questions

Comment: Andrew Leap : thats why i posted this question otherwise i can follow the answer of other related questions on this site, but i got two or three same answers on each question, which are not useful to me